Why Does Seder Kodashim Have so Many Girsa Substitutions/Textual Emendations?
The Talmudic tractates of Seder Kodashim are notorious for girsa changes/textual emendations. A study partner of mine was so challenged by the textual substitutions in tractate Temura that he joked about the notion of Temura really coming alive (Temura deals with substituting/attempting to switch sacred sacrificial animals - the pun being that the textual substitutions in that tractate were endless). Why?

If something is studied much less, would you expect it to be better preserved or worse?

The changes in girsa are definitely difficult to handle. I recommend relying on Rabbeinu Gershom as much as possible (small print on the inside of the page in lots of kodshim, including Temurah). He often fully explains the topic, and his girsa often makes more sense than the others do. Also, Likutei Halachos from the Chofetz Chaim will definitely help you to get a final view of each topic. The most important mistake to avoid is checking different girsas before you finished understanding the piece according to one. (I know it's super tempting to follow the little letters!)
